# Satisfying peerDependencies with devDependencies in npm3

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

So NPM 3 has removed automatic resolving of peer dependencies which is great, however in the scenario of developing a plugin/library to be consumed by an application elsewhere if I make the underlying library use `peerDependencies` which is the correct notion here, it means if anyone wants to work on that library they need to manually resolve all dependencies.

So rather than having them do that it seems logical that I could put the same dependencies into `devDependencies` to satisfy the local development scenario, so anyone consuming it would need to explicitly satisfy the peers, anyone developing the library further would get the peer dependencies for free via the `devDependencies`.

So the question is, is there anything wrong with that? as I can find very little info on how to sensibly handle `peerDependencies` in NPM3 in any automatic fashion.

=== Update ===

As mentioned in the comments, when I tried doing things this way it is not compatible with earlier versions of npm, so npm >= 3.0 work fine with this approach and it satisfies the criteria automatically for a developer to check out `npm install` and be productive, however if you were to do this on an earlier version of NPM it blows up around peer dependencies not met and does not seem to work.

I post this as I hope this incompatibility with earlier versions is somehow down to my incompetence in some way so I can both support ease of development for people who just want to `npm install` on this package to develop for it, but also previous versions. So if you know a better way or a way around this or other issues this introduces please speak up.

Comment: I have tried this approach but then it seems to blow up on the build server, saying `EPEERINVALID` that it cannot satisfy sibling dependency. This is specifically consuming a dependency via github so not sure if this is unrelated, but it seems to work ok locally.

Comment: The above comment issue may be down to the build server running npm2 and not npm3, which introduces even more complexity if this approach can only be used for npm3 and wont work with earlier versions.

Comment: comment spam, so turns out npm2 does not light above approach, moved to npm3 and it works fine, so I would watch out for this approach if consumers may be needing to build it without npm3.

Comment: Add your UPDATE as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asked to post this as the answer so here you go:

> As mentioned in the comments, when I tried doing things this way it is not compatible with earlier versions of npm, so npm >= 3.0 work fine with this approach and it satisfies the criteria automatically for a developer to check out npm install and be productive, however if you were to do this on an earlier version of NPM it blows up around peer dependencies not met and does not seem to work.

> I post this as I hope this incompatibility with earlier versions is somehow down to my incompetence in some way so I can both support ease of development for people who just want to npm install on this package to develop for it, but also previous versions. So if you know a better way or a way around this or other issues this introduces please speak up.